# Duvida, somar com valor de um array [AnyObject] usando Swift?

Tags: swift

Como eu faria isso em swift?

```
var jogador02 = ["Teste", 0]

jogador02[1] += 1
```

Resultado ser igual a

```
jogador02 = ["teste", 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você misturou os tipos de seu array, tudo se torna `AnyObject`, logo para efetuar a operação binaria de soma você precisa **tipar** o dado.

```
var jogador02 = ["Teste", 0]
var temp = jogador02[1] as! Int
temp += 1 // Pode substituir por temp++
jogador02[1] = temp
```

---

Eu recomendaria que você criasse uma classe jogador com os atributos desejados, no caso ficaria assim:

```
class Jogador {

  var nome = ""
  var pontuacao = 0    

}
```

E na hora de utilizar:

```
var jogador = Jogador()
jogador.pontuacao += 1
```

Comment: Verdade @LeoDabus, não lembrava o nome no momento e achei que levava o mesmo da classe, corrigido.

Comment: `+1` exatamente isto, se fosse apenas de números não teria a necessidade de forcar a conversão para Int :)

Comment: Outro detalhe você tá forçando unwrap do elemento sem ter certeza de que é um Int, o que levaria a um crash do App caso contrário

Comment: A maneira mais fácil seria usar ?? Nil coalescing operator em conjunto com `as? Int ?? 0`

Comment: Muito Obrigado galera, todos me ajudaram muito! todas as respostas ajudaram muito!

Comment: Outra coisa você deve declarar `let jogador = Jogador()` o que não impede você de alterar as propriedades pontuação e nome.